# Can not understand the logic of this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This query is trying to get the `s1ppmp` (the price of product) of each `s1ilie` (size), each `s1iref` (reference) and `s1ydat` (the lastest date) for the price, because one product could have more than one price on different dates, for example, during the black friday or the normal price for the other days.

The `anmoisjour` comes from calender table, but there is no connection between CALENDER table and main table `msk100`, so ... I don't understand the logic of this query...

```
SELECT s1isoc,
       s1ilie,
       s1iref,
       s1ydat,
       anmoisjour,
       s1ppmp
FROM msk110
     INNER JOIN (SELECT s1isoc AS isoc,
                        s1ilie AS ilie,
                        s1iref AS iref,
                        MAX(s1ydat) AS ydat,
                        anmoisjour
                 FROM calendrier,
                      msk110
                 WHERE s1ydat <= anmoisjour
                   AND anmoisjour BETWEEN 20100101 AND 20302131
                 GROUP BY s1isoc,
                          s1ilie,
                          s1iref,
                          anmoisjour) a ON s1isoc = isoc
                                       AND s1ilie = ilie
                                       AND s1iref = iref
                                       AND s1ydat = ydat
WHERE s1isoc = 1
  AND anmoisjour BETWEEN 20100101 AND 20302131
ORDER BY anmoisjour,
         s1ydat;
```

s1isoc, s1ilie, s1iref, s1ydat,and s1ppmp comes from msk110 
and 
anmoisjour belongs to calender table, which is a date table.

Comment: You have a old style `CROSS JOIN` in the subquery: `FROM calendrier, msk110`. That should really be a proper join: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: I also recommend uses aliases and qualifying your columns names with them. For those that don't know your environment (very) well we don't know what table a column like `s1ilie` or `anmoisjour` belongs to.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, s1isoc,
       s1ilie,
       s1iref,
       s1ydat,and s1ppmp comes from msk110 and anmoisjour belongs to calender table, which is a date table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the confusion is the way that the calendar table is joined.

If `anmoisjour` is the day column of the calendar table and this table holds 1 row per day, the `WHERE` filter `anmoisjour BETWEEN 20100101 AND 20302131` makes `calendrier` hold a row for each day for 20 years (2010 to 2030).

They way the product prices table `msk100` is linked to the calendar `calendrier` table is not directly by date, but with a max date (`msk100.s1ydat <= calendrier.anmoisjour`). This means that for example a date of `msk100.s1ydat` that's `2015-01-01` will join against ***every row*** of the calendar table thats between `2015-01-01` and `2030-12-31`.

The `GROUP BY` is by the calendar table's date (`calendrier.anmoisjour`) this means that if a particular product, size and price repeats on different dates, let's say the only occurrences are on dates `2015-01-01`, `2017-01-01` and `2020-01-01`, then the result of the group by would be the following (ordered by calendar date, displaying even `NULL` to demonstrate):

```
MAX(s1ydat)     anmoisjour

null            2010-01-01
null            ...
null            2014-12-31
2015-01-01      2015-01-01
2015-01-01      2015-01-02
2015-01-01      ...
2015-01-01      2016-01-01
2015-01-01      ...

2017-01-01      2017-01-01
2017-01-01      2017-01-02
2017-01-01      ...
2017-01-01      2019-12-31

2020-01-01      2020-01-01
2020-01-01      2025-01-01
2020-01-01      ...
```

What your query is showing is the contents of the product table ***with the last date that that particular product had that particular price***, for each day over 20 years, also where `s1isoc = 1` (which I don't know what that means).

Comment: Your description is very clear. Thank you so much ! The s1isoc means" id of the company", but it dosen't metter.